# How do you retain a checkbox value on a dynamic table that you can add,edit and remove from?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to allow the user to edit the values they enter into the table but there is a checkbox that I want to disable when it is not in an editable state and also retain its checked or unchecked state as the user inputs it or edits it.

Currently, the checkbox can be checked even when it is not being edited and doesn't retain its checked state.

The code below is what I have regarding this.

```js
$(function () {
    //Add, Save, Edit and Delete functions code
    $(".btnEdit").on("click", Edit);
    $(".btnDelete").on("click", Delete);
    $("#btnAdd").on("click", Add);
});

function Add() {

    $("#tblData tbody").append(
        "<tr>" +
        "<td><input type='text' /></td>" +
        "<td><input type='text' /></td>" +
        "<td><input type='checkbox' /></td>" +
        "<td><span class='btnSave'> <a href='#' class='btn btn-link'>Save</a></span>|<span class='btnDelete'> <a href='#' class='btn btn-link'>Delete</a></span></td>" +
        "</tr>"
    );

    $(".btnSave").on("click", Save);
    $(".btnDelete").on("click", Delete);
};

function Save() {
    var par = $(this).parent().parent(); //tr

    var tdName = par.children("td:nth-child(1)");
    var tdPhone = par.children("td:nth-child(2)");
    var tdEmail = par.children("td:nth-child(3)");
    var tdButtons = par.children("td:nth-child(4)");

    tdName.html(tdName.children("input[type=text]").val());
    tdPhone.html(tdPhone.children("input[type=text]").val());
    tdEmail.html(tdEmail.children("input[type=checkbox]").val());
    tdButtons.html("<span class='btnEdit'> <a href='#' class='btn btn-link'>Edit</a></span><span class='btnDelete'> <a href='#' class='btn btn-link'>Delete</a></span>");

    $(".btnEdit").on("click", Edit);
    $(".btnDelete").on("click", Delete);
};

function Edit() {
    var par = $(this).parent().parent(); //tr
    var tdName = par.children("td:nth-child(1)");
    var tdPhone = par.children("td:nth-child(2)");
    var tdEmail = par.children("td:nth-child(3)");
    var tdButtons = par.children("td:nth-child(4)");

    tdName.html("<input type='text' id='txtName' value='" + tdName.html() + "'/>");
    tdPhone.html("<input type='text' id='txtPhone' value='" + tdPhone.html() + "'/>");
    tdEmail.html("<input type='checkbox' id='txtEmail' value='" + tdEmail.html() + "'/>");
    tdButtons.html("</td><span class='btnSave'> <a href='#' class='btn btn-link'>Save</a></span></td>");

    $(".btnSave").on("click", Save);
    $(".btnEdit").on("click", Edit);
    $(".btnDelete").on("click", Delete);
};

function Delete() {
    var par = $(this).parent().parent(); //tr
    par.remove();
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnAdd">New</button>
<table id="tblData">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: In some places you refer to `tdEmail` as an `input` of type text, in others as a checkbox... it is confusing. Also, would be much better to use classes (like: `.td-name`) to find the elements instead of `td:nth-child(1)`, for example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can preserve the state of checkbox by checking `checked attribute`.

If the checked attribute exists, the checkbox will be checked and in unchecked condition it will blank.

---

**In Save function**:

**Change this**

```
tdEmail.html(tdEmail.children("input[type=checkbox]").val());
```

**To This**

```
 var email=(tdEmail.children("input[type=checkbox]").prop('checked')==true)?"checked":"";
 tdEmail.html("<input type='checkbox' disabled  id='txtEmail'" + email + "/>");
```

---

---

**In Edit function**:

**Change this**

```
tdEmail.html("<input type='checkbox' id='txtEmail' value='" + tdEmail.html() + "'/>");
```

**To this**

```
var email=(tdEmail.children("input[type=checkbox]").prop('checked')==true)?"checked":""; 
tdEmail.html("<input type='checkbox' id='txtEmail'" + email + "/>");
```

---

```js
$(function () {
            //Add, Save, Edit and Delete functions code
            $(".btnEdit").on("click", Edit);
            $(".btnDelete").on("click", Delete);
            $("#btnAdd").on("click", Add);
        });

        function Add() {

            $("#tblData tbody").append(
                "<tr>" +
                "<td><input type='text' /></td>" +
                "<td><input type='text' /></td>" +
                "<td><input type='checkbox' /></td>" +
                "<td><span class='btnSave'> <a href='#' class='btn btn-link'>Save</a></span>|<span class='btnDelete'> <a href='#' class='btn btn-link'>Delete</a></span></td>" +
                "</tr>");

            $(".btnSave").on("click", Save);
            $(".btnDelete").on("click", Delete);
        };

        function Save() {
            var par = $(this).parent().parent(); //tr

            var tdName = par.children("td:nth-child(1)");
            var tdPhone = par.children("td:nth-child(2)");
            var tdEmail = par.children("td:nth-child(3)");
            var tdButtons = par.children("td:nth-child(4)");
            
     
     tdName.html(tdName.children("input[type=text]").val());
            tdPhone.html(tdPhone.children("input[type=text]").val());
        var emailCheck= tdEmail.children("input[type=checkbox]").prop('checked');
        //console.log(emailCheck);
        var email=(emailCheck==true)?"checked":"";
         //console.log(email);
         tdEmail.html("<input type='checkbox' disabled  id='txtEmail'" + email + "/>");
        
            tdButtons.html("<span class='btnEdit'> <a href='#' class='btn btn-link'>Edit</a></span><span class='btnDelete'> <a href='#' class='btn btn-link'>Delete</a></span>");

            $(".btnEdit").on("click", Edit);
            $(".btnDelete").on("click", Delete);
            
             
        };

        function Edit() {
            var par = $(this).parent().parent(); //tr
            var tdName = par.children("td:nth-child(1)");
            var tdPhone = par.children("td:nth-child(2)");
            var tdEmail = par.children("td:nth-child(3)");
            var tdButtons = par.children("td:nth-child(4)");
                  var emailCheck= tdEmail.children("input[type=checkbox]").prop('checked');
        //console.log(emailCheck);
        var email=(emailCheck==true)?"checked":""; 
            tdName.html("<input type='text' id='txtName' value='" + tdName.html() + "'/>");
            tdPhone.html("<input type='text' id='txtPhone' value='" + tdPhone.html() + "'/>");
            tdEmail.html("<input type='checkbox' id='txtEmail'" + email + "/>");
            tdButtons.html("</td><span class='btnSave'> <a href='#' class='btn btn-link'>Save</a></span></td>");

            $(".btnSave").on("click", Save);
            $(".btnEdit").on("click", Edit);
            $(".btnDelete").on("click", Delete);
        };

        function Delete() {
            var par = $(this).parent().parent(); //tr
            par.remove();
        };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnAdd">New</button>
<table id="tblData">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

**Note:** There may be more better ways to write your code but here I have pointed out solution to your problem.